# SQL query to find out some of three fields from three different table

Tags: database, mysql

I have three tables, tableA (id, A), tableB (id,B) and tableC (id,C). id is unique and primary key. Now I want to run a query on these three tables to find out sum of values of A,B and C for every id. (i.e. if id 1 is present in tableA but not in tableB then value B should be considered as 0 for id 1).example: tableA:

```
id  A
1   5
2   6
3   2
5   7
```

tableB:

```
id  B
2   5
3   8
4   1
```

tableC:

```
id  C
5   2
```

the output should be:

```
id  Sum
1   (5 + 0 + 0 =)5
2   (6 + 5 + 0 =)11
3   (2 + 8 + 0 =)10
4   (0 + 1 + 0 =)1
5   (7 + 0 + 2 =)9
```

Comment: Suggest you change the question title to "SQL query to find out sum of three fields from three different tables" for greater clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get a distinct list ( *UNION* ) of the IDs so that you include all, then LEFT JOIN to add the values together.

Something like

```
SELECT  IDs.ID,
         IFNULL(tableA.A,0) + IFNULL(tableB.B,0) + IFNULL(tableC.C,0) SumVal
FROM    (
            SELECT  ID
            FROM    tableA
            UNION
            SELECT  ID
            FROM    tableB
            UNION
            SELECT  ID
            FROM    tableC
        ) IDs LEFT JOIN
        tableA ON IDs.ID = tableA.ID LEFT JOIN
        tableB ON IDs.ID = tableB.ID LEFT JOIN
        tableC ON IDs.ID = tableC.ID
```

Comment: Not downvoting, but is this not overly complicated compared to the other answers?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
select id, sum(val) from
( select id, "A" as val from "tableA"
  union all
  select id, "B" as val from "tableB"
  union all
  select id, "C" as val from "tableC" ) as joined
group by id
order by id
```

Comment: I don't think "A"/"tableA"/"B"/"tableB"/"C"/"tableC" should be in quotes. They're not text literals.

Comment: Well it's good practice to include them if you're using postgresql (my database of choice) although they are only needed when 1. you are having column or table names which would be reserved keywords in PG or 2. (more common) when using characters such as underscore in table or column names.

Answer (score 1):

I could not test it with MySql but this works my databases (HSQLDB, Oracle):

```
select ID, sum(X) from 
  (SELECT  ID, A as X FROM    tableA
   UNION
   SELECT  ID, B as X FROM    tableB
   UNION
   SELECT  ID, C as X FROM    tableC)
group by ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the exact MySQL syntax, but this works in SQL Server:

```
SELECT ID, SUM(ColToSum) As SumValue FROM
(
SELECT ID, A As ColToSum FROM TableA
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, B As ColToSum FROM TableB
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, C As ColToSum FROM TableC
) Combined
GROUP BY ID
```

Remember to use "UNION ALL", not just "UNION" which strips out duplicate rows as it combines (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)